# How to wrap / nest javascript calls that use 'this'?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am writing a function which accepts a `Button` object and should set `onclick` client script which conditionally calls the *existing* client script. For example, if I start with a button which would render like:

```
<input type="button" value="ok" id="ok"
  onclick="existingClickHandler(this);"
  />
```

I want to programmatically set `OnClientClick` on this button so it would render something like:

```
<input type="button" value="ok" id="ok"
  onclick="Wrapper(function { existingClickHandler(this); });"
  />
```

The problem is that the existing code uses `this`, I don't know how to write `Wrapper()` in such a way that `this` still points to the correct object.

How can I make the `existingClickHandler` continue to operate properly when called by `Wrapper()`?

---

Update: Per request, the scenario is I am writing an ASP.NET function to disable buttons on click, in order to prevent double-posts, and for some UI responsiveness. In my server-side C# code I have a function (this has been condensed a bit for clarity):

```
void AutoDisableButtons(Button sourceButton, params Button[] buttonsToDisable)
{
    string oldScript = sourceButton.OnClientClick;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldScript))
        oldScript = "null";
    else
        oldScript = "function(){" + oldScript + ";}";
    postbackEventScript = ....
    buttonsToDisableArrayScript = ....
    sourceButton.OnClientClick = "return DisableButtonsOnSubmit.call(this, " + oldScript + ", " + postbackEventScript + ", " + buttonsToDisableArrayScript + ");";
}
```

And the corresponding client script:

```
function DisableButtonsOnSubmit(oldClickScript, postbackEventReference, buttonsToDisableArray)
{
    if((typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') && !Page_ClientValidate())
        return false;
    if((typeof(oldClickScript) == 'function') && !oldClickScript.call(this))
        return false;
    for (var i=0; i<buttonsToDisableArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(null != document.getElementById(buttonsToDisableArray[i]))
        {
            document.getElementById(buttonsToDisableArray[i]).disabled = true;
        }
    }
    postbackEventReference.call(this);
    return true;
}
```

Note that this code includes the `.call()` solution proposed by @herostwist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to pass the button to `existingClickHandler` and still have `this` reference a different object within `existingClickHandler`.

That assumption being true try this:

```
<input type="button" value="ok" id="ok"
  onclick="existingClickHandler.call(SomeObjectForThis, this);"
/>
```

Where `SomeObjectForThis` is the object you want `this` to reference within `existingClickHandler`

Comment: if you want to understand what the `.call` does: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

Comment: I didn't know about `call`, but this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Huh if you're passing `this` as argument # 1, and not set the context, why not just use `onclick="existingClickHandler(this)"`? `this` will be argument # 1 as in your code...

Comment: @tenfour Could you share with us the actual code you're using now? I'm very curious. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set an object reference 'this' will point to the global window object. The thing is by using the input's onclick in the html tag you loose the ability to do that.

What you want is probably something like this (using jquery)

$('#id').click(function clickHandler(){
 // code here
});

Once you have done that you have the ability to call your handler in the correct scope

Answer (score 0):

this should be helpful: http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx

You could use a delegate:

```
onclick="var me = this; Wrapper(function { existingClickHandler(me); });"
```

Comment: I cannot modify the existing code, and even so the code needs to run in the right scope. I think @Zachary K is on to something here though so I'm experimenting there.

Answer (score 0):

You can store 'this' in a variable and use the variable instead:

```
<input type="button" value="ok" id="ok"
  onclick="var that=this; Wrapper(function { existingClickHandler(that); });"
  />
```